# Facebook-Canvas dosnt work on mobile-version

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I make a Facebook-Canvas App like last year. But On this Year is the problem that will not work on Mobile-Devices. 
When i Post my App on my Test-Facebook-Page and i want open with my Mobile-Device, it coming a error-message "The requested page could not be found".

**My Settings:**
[image: my Settings picture]

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has recently disabled the automatic redirect of canvas links to the mobile site URL for a large number of apps, because some apps were using it to redirect users to malware sites.

Here’s the bug report for this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1051463851558493/

It mentions a form where you can request that the feature be enabled again for your app.